# What Compendium entries cannot be bought from Purah's Assistant?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Once Purah unlocks the Camera function at the Hateno Tech Lab, her assistant offers to fill in your Hyrule Compendium in exchange for rupees - 100 for each entry. I spent a good amount of rupees buying every entry I could, and I've reached the point where he no longer has anything left to sell me, but I still have a handful of creatures and weapons I haven't discovered yet. What entries am I missing, and how do I get them?

Comment: For starters, I don't believe any of the boss monsters (Blights and/or Ganon) can be purchased.

Comment: @Steve-O Boss Monsters can be purchase, but only after completing the game. Once you have completed the game you will have a little star on your save game when you load it, your sheika map will also have completion tracking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After defeating Ganon, and entering the post-game, the following extra pictures can be purchased at 500 Rupees per picture, in the "Elite Enemies" section:

- All Silver Enemies (e.g. Silver Lynel, Silver Moblin, Silver Bokoblin, etc.)
- All one-time only enemies (e.g. Bosses)

The following picture can also be purchased for 100 Rupees, in the "Weapons" category:

- Light Bow

Answer (score 4):

After reading the comments on my question, I realized I had purchased all the pictures after facing the final Divine Beast and before fighting Ganon. Turns out I had two pictures that were available to purchase; a weapon and an "Elite Enemy" picture, a new category with a gold icon that was not there before I fought Ganon. The weapon was the Light Bow, and the Elite Enemy was Master Kohga. Upon purchasing these, Symin informed me that I had obtained every picture in the compendium. So it turns out there is an opportunity to purchase previously unbuyable pictures post-game.

Answer (score 0):

The strict answer to the question "what Compendium entries cannot be bought from Purah's Assistant?" is that there is precisely one (1) item that **cannot** be purchased and **must** be photographed by the player. The good news, is that it's not missable. This unique compendium entry is.....

The sunshroom.

[image: hyrule compendium sunshroom default (not available in-game)]

In order to unlock the option to purchase pictures from Symin, you need to take a picture of a sunshroom and show it to him. Once you have logged a personal picture of an item, it's removed from the available pictures to purchase. According to [a Gamefaqs thread](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75414678), a "default" sunshroom picture does exist in the game files (pictured above), but it's impossible to obtain in-game. The linked thread does claim to have *found* the actual sunshroom in the default picture and offers a location and time of day to recreate the default picture.

Source: I completed a Hyrule compendium using only purchased picture and an ungodly number of rupees